# SQL Difference Between adding 2 columns and the SUM of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am basically brand new at SQL and have hopefully a simple questions.

I was going through a sqlbolt tutorial (https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution) and got 2 radically different answers based on the following:

```
SELECT director, SUM(domestic_sales + international_sales) 
           as Cumulative_sales_from_all_movies
FROM movies
INNER JOIN boxoffice ON movies.id = boxoffice.movie_id
GROUP BY Director
```

Vs.

```
SELECT director, (domestic_sales + international_sales) 
           as Cumulative_sales_from_all_movies
FROM movies
INNER JOIN boxoffice ON movies.id = boxoffice.movie_id
GROUP BY Director
```

I just would like to know the difference.

Thank you :)

Comment: and now the "approved edit" causes the text to horizontal scroll making it harder to read.  I'd rather have the multiple column values on new rows to prevent horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

The second version is not valid SQL and should not work in any database.  Due to a mis-feature in MySQL, "bare" columns are allowed in an aggregation query.

You should set the configuration of your database so `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is set (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)).  This way, MySQL will conform to the standard SQL and almost every other database.

What is the difference?  The first version sums the values on all rows with the same director.  The second version returns the sum from an arbitrary row for that director.